# Find move order words in set

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, vector

This is an example because i have n random set with n random words in each set. 
EXAMPLE:
I have 3 sets of strings

```
Set1 {"hello","yes"}

Set2 {"dog","family"}

Set3 {"sea","sun"}
```

If I read from input: `C hello dog` -
I have to concatenate `Set1` and `Set2` `{C = Concatenate}`

If I read from input: `M dog sun` -
I have to move only the word  `dog` in `Set3` (delete it from `Set2`) `{M = Move}`

I think i need of vector `<list<string > >` tail; I have to search the two word in what set are and execute the command.

Also i need to optimize the memory, so maybe I should order each set, the search will be more faster.

Some advice on an appropriate way to do it? Thanks all.

Comment: There is not enough sample data here to know what your mechanism should be. Can you write your algorithm out in pseudocode?

Comment: I think you want a `std::vector<std::set<std::string> >`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly "concatenate Set1 and Set2" does? Does it return the result (to the calling function), does it put the result in one of the sets or does it add another set containing the result? If one of the latter two, does it remove the pre-concatenated sets or does it keep them? Since these are "sets", presumably it cannot contain duplicates, correct?

Comment: Yes, if i have C i have to move the content from a list to another. Is not important if duplicates, it empty a string and the content goes in the other